# How to add login Items by code to mountain lion osx

Tags: macos, login, osx-mountain-lion, login-items

Until I upgraded to Mountain Lion I was able to add login items by editing this plist:

```
/Users/test/Library/Preferences/loginwindow.plist
```

And adding items `(path,name,hide)` to `AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary` dictionary.

In the OS this doesn't work anymore. Items that are added to this dictionary are not launch on login.

I see that the save now the login items in a file called `com.apple.loginitems.plist`, but I dont undersand how to add an item to this file.

I tried to add the item to `CustomListItems` dictionary with parameters like `name,path, hide`, but they were not launched on login.

Does anyone know how can I add from code login item?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use AppleScript:

`osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to make login item at end with properties {path:"/Applications/iTunes.app", hidden:true}'`